# Limit and differentiablility of $\ \sum \frac{(-1)^n\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{n} $

Tags: limits, derivatives

I have to estimate the value of the limit and test whether it is differentiable:

$$\ f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{n} $$

I was trying to escalculate the limit:

$$\ \frac{1}{n}\sin(\frac{x}{n}) $$

However it didn't lead to anything. I would apprecite any help.

Comment: Please check if the argument of sine is $nx$ instead of $x/n$.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's x/n